# Is calling a staff member "selfish" harassment?

Tags: ethics, etiquette, harassment

A faculty member wrote to a staff member that "you are selfish." The staff member wrote back to the faculty member asking for an explanation. The faculty member did not respond and wrote: "I would not respond to you any further." Is this harassment?

Comment: Please provide more details in order for us to understand the question. Who from the faculty? Who is the staff? What is the reason?

Comment: From the faculty. The faculty did not the reason.

Comment: Okay, but a faculty cannot write an email. There must be some person who actually typed the email, right?

Comment: Likely this was not an email out of the blue, with no prior communication. So, lacking that other communication, this is impossible to answer.

Comment: Whether it *is* harassment is a matter of opinion, I think.  Whether it's something that's forbidden by your institution's rules or local law is an entirely different question that we can't answer, not knowing what those rules are.

Answer (score 10):

It's brusque and ill-advised, but it's not harassment *per se*.

Harassment is the creation of a hostile work environment through pressure or intimidation. A one-off heated email and the use of a single adjective to describe someone in a negative light is certainly not sufficient of proving anything more than the person who wrote the email probably should have waited a while before hitting the "send" button. A sustained campaign of emails and a larger pattern of behavior would be needed to make a believable harassment argument.

There's no reason for this to be escalated into a larger situation that will ultimately accomplish very little except inflaming tensions further.

Comment: Then what will be requirements of "harassment"? What will be needed to prove that there is a harassment?

Comment: See my revision.

Comment: There are multiple that the faculty eventually banned a staff from any discussions and meetings.

Comment: That's not in your original question. And it's still not clear that it's harassment.

Comment: If this is the US, in order to qualify as harassment legally, the behavior in question also has to be based on a protected characteristic (i.e. sex, race, age, etc). Calling a staff member "selfish" because they are Jewish = harassment; calling a staff member "selfish" because you don't like their shoes = not harassment.

Comment: @nengel Could you please give a link to the list of protected characters in USA?

Comment: @nengel ehm... no. Just look up how many times the word harassment is used in the US Code. There's 170 sections that contain the word harass. "protected class" are just relevant for *title VII discrimination*